# Sapper: How do I fix `parentNode is null` when navigating away from a page with kwes.io form?

Tags: svelte, sapper

I'm creating a contact form using [kwes.io](https://kwes.io) inside SapperJS. The form itself works.

But once I land on the contact page I cannot navigate away from it using Sapper links, but normal https links work.

The URL in browser changes, but the content doesn't load. Then to load the content I have to reload the page.

I contacted the support team from Kwes, but they say it has something to do with the way Sapper handles routing and can't help.

I created my form like this

```html
<svelte:head>
  <script src="https://kwes.io/js/kwes.js"></script>
</svelte:head>


<div class="kwes-form">
    <form method="POST" action="https://kwes.io/api/foreign/forms/YOUR_FORM_KEY">
        <label for="name">Your Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

On Chrome browser console it prints

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null`

and on Firefox console this

`TypeError: t.parentNode is null`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ran into this error recently. In my case it was due to another library changing the DOM. (In my case fontawesome)

### Debugging

I debugged it by placing a break point where the error occurred

```js
function detach(node) {
    if (!node.parentNode) debugger; // added breakpoint
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
}
```

I figured out which node caused the error and saw that indeed it was no longer in the DOM (fontawesome had replaced it with an `<svg>` tag)

### Solution

My solution was to wrap the node in another node. So that svelte isn't relying on a node that is being replaced.

#### Before

```
{#if condition}
  <span class="fa fa-check"/>
{/if}
```

#### After

```
{#if condition}
  <span>
    <span class="fa fa-check"/>
  </span>
{/if}
```

Comment: I'm still getting this error with standalone Svelte 3.20.1, this allowed me to add a workaround, so thanks!